# @SqlBatch making multiple inserts in jdbi sql object api

Tags: java, mysql, dropwizard, jdbi

```
public interface UserDBDao {
    @SqlBatch ("INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (:user.id, :user.name)")
    void createAllUsers(@BindBean("user") List<User> users);
}
```

When I try to insert multiple rows using the above method, even after using @SqlBatch it is making multiple insert queries. The Sql log is as follows

```
2019-12-18T09:33:41.375486Z    22 Query SET autocommit=0
2019-12-18T09:33:41.376469Z    22 Query SELECT @@session.transaction_read_only
2019-12-18T09:33:41.376791Z    22 Query INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (1000, 'a0')
2019-12-18T09:33:41.377059Z    22 Query INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (1001, 'a1')
2019-12-18T09:33:41.377248Z    22 Query INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (1002, 'a2')
2019-12-18T09:33:41.377427Z    22 Query INSERT INTO user (id, name) VALUES (1003, 'a3')
2019-12-18T09:33:41.377618Z    22 Query commit
2019-12-18T09:33:41.377903Z    22 Query SET autocommit=1
```

How to insert all records in single push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the log it opens the transaction and does it in one go. So basically you're achieveing "single push" anyway. Unfortunately you can't union multiple inserts into one unless you want to do it yourself with direct JDBC queries or *Dialect extension.

Comment: Hey @Alexey thanks for the answer. Is there any difference between doing 1. opening transaction and pushing it using multiple statements and 2. using single insert statement in terms of time and resources.

Comment: Hey. If you have stable db connection with low ping difference is almost nothing. Unless it becomes your culprit I wouldn't go for optimization as it will take more effort compared to result you'll get.

Comment: So with the @SqlBatch my dropwizard application will open one connection push all the data and close it right. It wont open connection for each of the insert and close it right. Am I correct?

Comment: Yep, that's true. Transactions live inside one connection, if dropwizard  closes connection after each statement transaction would be lost.